# Three.js: Is there any way to take bounding box for group

Tags: javascript, three.js

Can I take bounding box for the groups in threejs. I have a list of objects in three.js where I group them all in single unit. I want to get the height and width of the groups , So i tried to using Box3 to determine the height and width. Is there any way to get the height and width of the group of objects in threejs

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x00ff00} );

var cubeA = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
cubeA.position.set( 100, 100, 0 );

var cubeB = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
cubeB.position.set( -100, -100, 0 );

//create a group and add the two cubes
//These cubes can now be rotated / scaled etc as a group
var group = new THREE.Group();
group.add( cubeA );
group.add( cubeB );

scene.add( group );
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [Box3.setFromObject()](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Box3.setFromObject) to compute the AABB for a group of objects. Code example:

```js
const aabb = new THREE.Box3();
aabb.setFromObject( group );
```

`three.js R118`

Answer (score 4):

A [`Group`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/objects/Group) inherits from `Object3D`, so you can use [`.setFromObject`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/math/Box3.setFromObject) from `Box3`, and then `.getSize`

```
let bb = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(group);
let size = bb.getSize(new THREE.Vector3());
```

That will give you the size of the bounding box of the Group